# Vuejs template : "Cannot read properties of null" but Array is defined

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs3, associative-array

I want to display an array elements in my Vuejs template.

I am getting data from API, formatting them into an associative Array with a function and then trying to display in the template :

```
export default {
  components: {
    DefaultHeader,
    DefaultFooter
  },
  data() {
    return {
      info: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.refreshData();
  },
  methods: {
    refreshData() {
      infoService.getInfo(this.$route.params.id)
        .then(response => {
          this.info = FormatHelper.BInfoFormat(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
  }
}
```

When i try to display the first element in the template with this code :

```
{{ this.info.name }}
```

I get the error :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null
> (reading 'name')

But when I display the full Array Object at the exact same place in code, I can see that it's defined :

```
{{ this.info }}
```

shows :

```
{ "name": "B3", "call": "about", "G": "H" }
```

Also, I get the right data when i try to console log in my mounted() component function :

```
console.log(this.info.name)
```

What is wrong in the way I am trying to access data getting me this error ?

Comment: is `this.info` initially `null` and gets populated later? try `{{ this.info?.name }}` - without atual code, or at least enough to know what `this.info` is, there's many reasons this will occur

Comment: When i try ```{{ this.info?.name }}``` the display is right, i get the name without any error, what is it doing ?
And yes, this.info is first defined at null.

Comment: `is first defined at null` and `null` has no properties, therefore the error - either initially defined it as `{}` rather than `null` (though this may break other logic) or use `v-if` to conditionally show `.name` or use what I suggested - the actual reason would be easy to describe with some meaningful code in your question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author answered without accepting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks to comments :

in :

```
export default {
  components: {
    DefaultHeader,
    DefaultFooter
  },
  data() {
    return {
      info: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.refreshData();
  },
  methods: {
    refreshData() {
      infoService.getInfo(this.$route.params.id)
        .then(response => {
          this.info = FormatHelper.BInfoFormat(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
  }
}
```

replace :

```
  data() {
    return {
      info: null,
    };
  },
```

by :

```
  data() {
    return {
      info: {},
    };
  },
```

The initial define at null is breaking the Array methods I was trying to use in the template.

Comment: marked it solved, otherwise it draws attention of solvers

Comment: I cannot accept my own answer, it requires 22 more hours to wait